# how to mock out an Observable? I have tried to mock it out three different ways

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, rxjs6

I have written many unit tests to test observables, but for some reason, this test is not working like the other ones I've written, but I dont see what the issue is.

I would like a mock for ChangePasswordFacade.successful$ to return an Observable that returns true.  Even though I have previously used the mocking strategy below, it's not working. I tried injecting ChangePasswordFacade into the test.  I tried using a mock successful$ function in the useValue of the TestBed provider. And I tried the approach below.  They all yield sucessful$ as false.  How can I mock this out differently to return true?

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { PasswordChangeModalComponent } from './password-change-modal.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { PasswordChangeFormComponent } from '../../..';
import { DefaultPopoverComponent } from '@bis-angular/shared-components/pattern-library';
import { Store, StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import {
  ChangePasswordFacade,
  UserInformationFacade,
  changePasswordInitialState,
  CHANGEPASSWORD_FEATURE_KEY,
  changePasswordReducer
} from '@bis-angular/users';
import { configureTestSuite } from 'ng-bullet';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

describe('PasswordChangeModalComponent', () => {
  let component: PasswordChangeModalComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<PasswordChangeModalComponent>;

  const childDefaultPopoverComponent = jasmine.createSpyObj('DefaultPopoverComponent', ['hideModal', 'showModal']);
  const childPasswordChangeFormComponent = jasmine.createSpyObj('PasswordChangeFormComponent', ['setFormControlsToEmpty']);

  const changePasswordFacadeSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ChangePasswordFacade', ['resetState']);

  configureTestSuite(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        StoreModule.forRoot({}),
        StoreModule.forFeature(CHANGEPASSWORD_FEATURE_KEY, changePasswordReducer, {
          initialState: changePasswordInitialState
        })
      ],
      declarations: [PasswordChangeFormComponent, DefaultPopoverComponent, PasswordChangeModalComponent],
      providers: [Store, UserInformationFacade, ChangePasswordFacade]
    });
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PasswordChangeModalComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.defaultPopoverComponent = childDefaultPopoverComponent;

    component.watchSuccessful = { unsubscribe: () => {} };
    spyOn(component.watchSuccessful, 'unsubscribe');
    const service = TestBed.get(ChangePasswordFacade);
    spyOn(service, 'successful$').and.returnValue(of(true));
  });


  describe('showPasswordChangeModal function ', () => {
    it('should call showModal and then not hide if not successful  ', () => {
      spyOn(component, 'hidePasswordChangeModal');
      component.successful$.subscribe((successful: boolean) => {
        expect(component.hidePasswordChangeModal).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(changePasswordFacadeSpy.resetState).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(component.watchSuccessful.unsubscribe).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
      component.showPasswordChangeModal();
      expect(childDefaultPopoverComponent.showModal).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });


});
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { select, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { ChangePasswordPartialState } from './change-password.reducer';
import { changePasswordQuery } from './change-password.selectors';
import { ChangePassword, ChangePasswordResetState } from './change-password.actions';
import { NewPassword } from '@bis-angular/users';

@Injectable()
export class ChangePasswordFacade {
  successful$ = this.store.pipe(select(changePasswordQuery.getSuccessful));

  initiated$ = this.store.pipe(select(changePasswordQuery.getInitiated));

  constructor(private store: Store<ChangePasswordPartialState>) {}

  changePassword(newPassword: NewPassword, userId: string) {
    this.store.dispatch(new ChangePassword(newPassword, userId));
  }

  resetState() {
    this.store.dispatch(new ChangePasswordResetState());
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you by any chance declaring `ChangePasswordFacade` in the providers array of the `@Component` decorator for the class definition of `PasswordChangeModalComponent`?  If so, you'll need to use overrideComponent to successfully inject a mock provider.

Answer (score 0):

here is how I did it:  I used the store to dispatch an action to change successful$ to true.   it's now an integration test at this point, not a unit test.

```
import { ChangePasswordFacade, UserInformationFacade } from '@bis-angular/users';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { StoreModule, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { PasswordChangeModalComponent, PasswordChangeFormComponent } from '../../..';
import * as fromFeature from '@bis-angular/users';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { configureTestSuite } from 'ng-bullet';
import { DefaultPopoverComponent } from '@bis-angular/shared-components/pattern-library';

describe('PasswordChangeModalComponent', () => {
  let component: PasswordChangeModalComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<PasswordChangeModalComponent>;
  let store: Store<fromFeature.ChangePasswordState>;

  const childDefaultPopoverComponent = jasmine.createSpyObj('DefaultPopoverComponent', ['hideModal', 'showModal']);
  const childPasswordChangeFormComponent = jasmine.createSpyObj('PasswordChangeFormComponent', ['setFormControlsToEmpty']);

  configureTestSuite(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        StoreModule.forRoot({}),
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        StoreModule.forFeature(fromFeature.CHANGEPASSWORD_FEATURE_KEY, fromFeature.changePasswordReducer, {
          initialState: fromFeature.changePasswordInitialState
        })
      ],
      declarations: [PasswordChangeModalComponent, DefaultPopoverComponent, PasswordChangeFormComponent],
      providers: [ChangePasswordFacade, UserInformationFacade]
    });
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = TestBed.get(Store);
    spyOn(store, 'dispatch').and.callThrough();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PasswordChangeModalComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.defaultPopoverComponent = childDefaultPopoverComponent;
    component.watchSuccessful = { unsubscribe: () => {} };

    spyOn(component.watchSuccessful, 'unsubscribe');
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });


  describe('showPasswordChangeModal function ', () => {
    it('should call showModal and then hide if successful  ', () => {
      spyOn(component, 'hidePasswordChangeModal');
      spyOn(component.changePasswordService, 'resetState');
      const action = new fromFeature.ChangePasswordSuccessful({});

      store.dispatch(action);
      component.showPasswordChangeModal();

      component.successful$.subscribe((successful: boolean) => {
        expect(component.hidePasswordChangeModal).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(component.changePasswordService.resetState).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
      expect(childDefaultPopoverComponent.showModal).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Since, you want to access `successful$` which is defined at class level of `ChangePasswordFacade`.

something like:

```
export class ChangePasswordFacade{
   successful$:observable // ... something like this
}
```

You should try `useValue`:

```
 configureTestSuite(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        StoreModule.forRoot({}),
        StoreModule.forFeature(CHANGEPASSWORD_FEATURE_KEY, changePasswordReducer, {
          initialState: changePasswordInitialState
        })
      ],
      declarations: [PasswordChangeFormComponent, DefaultPopoverComponent, PasswordChangeModalComponent],
      providers: [Store, UserInformationFacade, 
                   {provide: ChangePasswordFacade , useValue: 
                     {
                         successful$ : of(true)
                     }
                   }'
                 ]
    });
  });
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.  I tried the exact approach you suggested above, as I noted in my initial problem description.  It did not work.

Comment: @user372225 : what values did you get from `succeessful$` when u tried my suggestion ?

Comment: hi @ShashankVivek, I get 'false' value for successful$  using your suggestion.

Comment: @user372225 even when you are setting setting it `of(true)` `true` ? some variable seems to manipulating it then